# Why am I getting incorrect values when reading the Manufacturer/Device ID using QuadSPI (STM32f4) from a W25Q32JV (Winbond Flash)?

Tags: c, stm32, spi

I understand need to send Instruction 0x90, followed by 3 dummy bytes 0x00 to external flash. The rest configuration is OK. The code is as following.

This is SPI_INIT function.

```
static void MX_QUADSPI_Init(void)
{

/\* QUADSPI parameter configuration\*/
hqspi.Instance = QUADSPI;
hqspi.Init.ClockPrescaler = 0;
hqspi.Init.FifoThreshold = 4;
hqspi.Init.SampleShifting = QSPI_SAMPLE_SHIFTING_HALFCYCLE;
hqspi.Init.FlashSize = 23;
hqspi.Init.ChipSelectHighTime = QSPI_CS_HIGH_TIME_2_CYCLE;
hqspi.Init.ClockMode = QSPI_CLOCK_MODE_0;
hqspi.Init.FlashID = QSPI_FLASH_ID_2;
hqspi.Init.DualFlash = QSPI_DUALFLASH_DISABLE;
if (HAL_QSPI_Init(&hqspi) != HAL_OK)
{
Error_Handler();
}
}
```

and the following function is used to read ID from Flash. The Manufacturing ID is of 1 byte and Device ID is of 2 bytes. So the length is 3. Address is 0x00. how to send 3 dummy bytes (0x00). Shall I edit dummy cycles for it? Or is there another way for this?

```
void QSPI_Flash_ID_Read(uint8_t \*data, int length, uint32_t address){

QSPI_AutoPollingMemReady(&hqspi);
QSPI_CommandTypeDef sCommand;

sCommand.InstructionMode   = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_1_LINE;
sCommand.AddressSize       = QSPI_ADDRESS_24_BITS;
sCommand.AlternateByteMode = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
sCommand.DdrMode           = QSPI_DDR_MODE_DISABLE;
sCommand.DdrHoldHalfCycle  = QSPI_DDR_HHC_ANALOG_DELAY;
sCommand.SIOOMode          = QSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;

/\* Reading Sequence ------------------------------------------------ \*/
sCommand.Instruction = 0x90;
sCommand.AddressMode = QSPI_ADDRESS_1_LINE;
sCommand.Address     = address;
sCommand.NbData      = length;
sCommand.DataMode    = QSPI_DATA_4_LINES;
sCommand.DummyCycles = 0;

HAL_QSPI_Command(&hqspi, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE);

HAL_QSPI_Receive(&hqspi, data, 1000);
}
```

Value read is incorrect.

Comment: Before you know the device type at the (Q-)SPI interface you can't assume that it will send the ID on 4 lines. If I remember correctly, that's the reason that the ID is sent on data line 0. Therefore you should favor data mode QSPI_DATA_1_LINE. -- I've sent 1 dummy byte to get the ID.

Comment: 1) If you issue a command that has nothing to do with reading actual data content, why do you have address mode as 1 line and not as "none"? You don't need to send any address. 2) You said you want 3 dummy cycles, but you set 0 dummy cycles. Try using 1 data line for return data as well. 3) You haven't posted QSPI flash initialization. What commands do you send to it before this moment to initialize its operation? Not every function of QSPI Flash works immediately after power on without sending a couple of instructions first. Hint: for debugging, you can reduce communication speed to 1MHz.

Comment: If you read the W25Q32JV datasheet carefully, for standard SPI you send CMD 0x90H to the chip, For DSPI, the command is 0x92H, and for QSPI, it is 0x94H.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED!

Current settings for SPI QUAD I/O. Refer to datasheet Section 8.2.25

https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Winbond%20PDFs/W25Q32JV_RevI_5-4-21.pdf

  /* Reading Sequence*/
  sCommand.Instruction = 0x94;
  
  sCommand.AddressMode = QSPI_ADDRESS_4_LINES;
  
  sCommand.Address     = address;//0x000000
  
  sCommand.NbData      = length;
  
  sCommand.DataMode    = QSPI_DATA_4_LINES;
  
  sCommand.DummyCycles = 4;